# F5 Mac Edge Client and Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, vpn, f5

I am an Android application developer and my MAC machine is in a corporate environment.The machine is connecting to VPN through F5 Mac VPN Edge Client,and after connection internet is not available in Android emulator.Is there anything I need to set on the machine or android emulator to take the machine network or please advice me on how to route the network.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that when you connect to the Corp VPN your routing table gets flushed with only what is needed to connect to the office. Once you disconnect from the VPN your routing table gets restored.

To see this in action do the following:

1. Disconnect from the VPN.
2. Open two terminal windows.
3. In the first window type in the following: `netstat -nr`
   Note: This will print out your disconnected Routing table.
4. Now connect using the vpn.
5. In the second window type in: `netstat -nr`

You will see route to the VM has been removed.

My company will not allow us to edit the routing table. I have tried. :(

In a terminal window type in the below.

```
sudo route -nv add -net 192.168.56 -interface vboxnet0
```

This will create a new static route. Just be aware that the F5 might remove it.